# Merging files from previous commit to current head

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-commit

I made a commit to the master branch sometime back which I revert back for some reason. Now few months have passed and I want to include those changes in my code again. I want to do this in my local repository by creating a new branch of the master in my local repository and add the changes from the reverted commit. Any help on how I can go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new branch from master easily, as you may already know:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b mynewbranch
```

And if you only want to pull in the changes from the one reverted commit, the simplest way is to cherry-pick it by its ID. Note this would be the ID of the commit you reverted; not the ID of the revert itself.

```
git cherry-pick {ID}
```

Depending on the context of the change, this may or may not result in a conflict. If it does then you would have to resolve it.

Comment: I will give a try!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have Git GUI installed, `cherry-pick`ing multiple commits gets easier.

```
1. Checkout the `master` branch
2. Visualize the `master` branch's history

     Repository > Visualize master's History

3. Checkout to the new branch from the main GUI window.
4. From the master's History window, scroll to the required commit(s), right-click

   "Cherry-pick this commit"
```

This adds the commit to the current active branch and may need to resolve any conflicts that arise.